# How to resize background image with CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have fullscreen website with `background-image: no-repeat` and `background-size: cover` style on it. I want to make animation that the background image will resize in 10 second to the right side of the page to `350px` width and `175px` height. It's even possible to do it?

```
body {
background-image: url(/image.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: fixed;
}
```

I saw some webkit animation but there was problem with the `background-size: cover` style, so the animation doesn't work.

I tried :

```
$(function(){
$('body').one("mouseover", function() {
    $('body').addClass('hover');
});
```

});

But it will resize the image instantly and move it to the right, I want to resize them linear.

Thank you very much guys! :-)

Comment: I believe you are looking for CSS Transitions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition

Comment: where's your body.hover css?

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You could add something like this to your css:

```
body {
    background-position: center center;
    transition: background-size 10s ease-in-out, background-position 10s ease-in-out;
}

body.hover {
    background-size: 350px 170px;
    background-position: right center;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oPbqPm

The problem with this, is however, that it won't animate the sizing.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you don't set the image as background. Instead, position the image behind all other elements using position and z-index properties. Once set, you can add the animation. For more details on using z-index and position attributes see the link below and "try it yourself" example:-

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp[enter link description here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

You can then use css animation for resizing of the imgae.

TO learn how to add animation see this link:-
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp